# How to check string for lettters (numberformatexception)

Tags: java

I have my code and it is able to check for letters on their own, but when i have them together in the same string it just crashes

I've tried the .matches method and ive also tried .contains which i thought would be the best fit but im not sure what would be the best to use.

```
   String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";

   System.out.println("How many dice to you want to roll?");
   String DiceChoice = scan.nextLine();



   while (DiceChoice.indexOf(".")!=-1 || DiceChoice.matches(regex)) {
       System.out.println("Please enter a number without a decimal or 
       letter");
       DiceChoice = s.nextLine();
   }
   int DiceChoiceInt = Integer.parseInt(DiceChoice);
```

When i put in "a" it is fine, or "." its fine but when i put in "4a" thats when i get the exception.

I expect it to find the letter somewhere in the string and go into the while loop but it just comes up with a number format exception, i was thinking maybe i could do a try catch possibly? Any help is appreciated

Comment: your regular expression only matches if there is nothing but letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern for a pure number string is `\d+`, so why not just check for that positive match instead:

```
String diceChoice;

do {
    diceChoice = scan.nextLine();
    if (diceChoice.matches("\\d+")) break;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number-only choice");
} while (true);

int diceChoiceInt = Integer.parseInt(diceChoice);
```

This approach will loop indefinitely until a pure number input happens.

Comment: I rolled the dice, and didn't crap out.  I am also happy with this result.